# How to use AND inside LINQ join

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, join

I'm trying to convert an SQL query to linq but do not know how to use the AND clause inside the join statement like i have in this example SQL Query.

I have highlighted the part i cannot figure out below.

```sql
DECLARE @GroupId INT = 10

SELECT 
    U.UserName, 
    U.UserID, 
    @GroupId AS "GroupID", 
    CASE WHEN GU.GROUPID IS NULL THEN 0 
         ELSE 1 END 
         AS InGroup 
FROM Users U
LEFT JOIN GroupUsers GU on GU.UserID = U.UserID 
    AND GU.GROUPID = @GroupId -- HERE!!
```

This is as close as I have got

```
from user in Users
join gu in GroupUsers on user.UserID equals gu.UserID into subq
from sub in subq.DefaultIfEmpty()
where sub.GroupID == 10 || sub == null
select new
{
    Username = user.UserName,
    UserId = user.UserID,
    GroupId = 10,
    InGroup = sub != null
}
```

but it using the `WHERE` removes data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could embed the `GroupId` condition into the query:

```
 from user in Users
 join gu in GroupUsers.Where(gu => gu.GroupID == 10)
    on user.UserID equals gu.UserID into subq
 from sub in subq.DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new 
 {
     Username = user.UserName,
     UserId = user.UserID,
     GroupId = 10,
     InGroup = sub != null
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do a join on multiple columns:

```
from user in Users
join gu in GroupUsers on new { user.UserID, user.GroupID } equals new { gu.UserID, gu.GroupID } subq
from sub in subq.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new 
{
   Username = user.UserName,
   UserId = user.UserID,
   GroupId = sub == null ? null : sub.GroupID,
   InGroup = sub != null
}
```